# Is $a^b+b^a$ unique for all integers a and b?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is  $a^b+b^a$ unique for all integers $a$ and $b$?

Any proof?

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and advice on [asking good questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959).

Comment: What thoughts do you have?

Comment: if a or b not equal to 1. then $a^b + b^a$ unique?

Answer (score 14):

No. For example,
$$
2^3 + 3^2 = 16^1 + 1^{16}
$$

Comment: Yes, nots of examples with $a=1$. In general $$a^b + b^a = (a^b+b^a-1)^1 + 1^{a^b+b^a-1}$$

Comment: Also, we trivially have $a^b+b^a = b^a+a^b$, so we might want to add a restriction like $a \ge b$.

Comment: Are there any examples not involving 1?

Comment: $2^0+0^2 = 1 = 3^0 + 0^3$ avoids the use of 1 if desired.

Comment: ok. What about no 1 or 0?

Answer (score 6):

I found no duplicates. These are the 744 smallest $a^b + b^a, \; \; a,b \geq 2.$ Evidently the closest near misses that ever happen are $(a=2,b=2n)$ and the very slightly larger $(a=4,b=n),$ let's say $n \geq 9.$

```
8  2   2
17  2   3
32  2   4
54  3   3
57  2   5
100  2   6
145  3   4
177  2   7
320  2   8
368  3   5
512  4   4
593  2   9
945  3   6
1124  2   10
1649  4   5
2169  2   11
2530  3   7
4240  2   12
5392  4   6
6250  5   5
7073  3   8
8361  2   13
16580  2   14
18785  4   7
20412  3   9
23401  5   6
32993  2   15
60049  3   10
65792  2   16
69632  4   8
93312  6   6
94932  5   7
131361  2   17
178478  3   11
262468  2   18
268705  4   9
397585  6   7
423393  5   8
524649  2   19
533169  3   12
1048976  2   20
1058576  4   10
1596520  3   13
1647086  7   7
1941760  6   8
2012174  5   9
2097593  2   21
4194788  2   22
4208945  4   11
4785713  3   14
7861953  7   8
8389137  2   23
9865625  5   10
10609137  6   9
14352282  3   15
16777792  2   24
16797952  4   12
33554432  8   8
33555057  2   25
43050817  3   16
45136576  7   9
48989176  5   11
61466176  6   10
67109540  2   26
67137425  4   13
129145076  3   17
134218457  2   27
177264449  8   9
244389457  5   12
268436240  2   28
268473872  4   14
292475249  7   10
364568617  6   11
387426321  3   18
536871753  2   29
774840978  9   9
1073742724  2   30
1073792449  4   15
1162268326  3   19
1173741824  8   10
1221074418  5   13
1996813914  7   11
2147484609  2   31
2179768320  6   12
3486792401  3   20
4294968320  2   32
4295032832  4   16
4486784401  9   10
6104053449  5   14
8589935681  2   33
8804293473  8   11
10460362464  3   21
13065520825  6   13
13877119009  7   12
17179870340  2   34
17179952705  4   17
20000000000  10   10
30518337500  5   15
31381070257  3   22
33739007300  9   11
34359739593  2   35
68719478032  2   36
68719581712  4   18
69149458432  8   12
78371693632  6   14
94143190994  3   23
96951758924  7   13
125937424601  10   11
137438954841  2   37
152588939201  5   16
274877908388  2   38
274878037265  4   19
282429550305  3   24
287589316833  9   12
470196375201  6   15
549755815409  2   39
550571544609  8   13
570623341222  11   11
678328486353  7   14
762940872982  5   17
847288625068  3   25
1061917364224  10   12
1099511629376  2   40
1099511787776  4   20
2199023257233  2   41
2541865845905  3   26
2552470327702  9   13
2821126684672  6   16
3814699155193  5   18
3881436747409  11   12
4398046512868  2   42
4398046705585  4   21
4399522300160  8   14
4747732369318  7   15
7625597504670  3   27
8796093024057  2   43
10137858491849  10   13
16926683582305  6   17
17592186046352  2   44
17592186278672  4   22
17832200896512  12   12
19073488804224  5   19
22876792476913  3   28
22897453501745  9   14
33233199005057  7   16
35184372090857  2   45
35186934979457  8   15
36314872537968  11   13
68630377389272  3   29
70368744179780  2   46
70368744457505  4   23
95367434840625  5   20
100289254654976  10   14
101559990680640  6   18
130291290501553  12   13
140737488357537  2   47
205891132121649  3   30
205929575454024  9   15
232630924325880  7   17
281474976712960  2   48
281474977042432  4   24
281479271677952  8   16
383799398752905  11   14
476837162287226  5   21
562949953423713  2   49
605750213184506  13   13
609359787056377  6   19
617673396313738  3   31
1000576650390625  10   15
1125899906845124  2   50
1125899907233249  4   25
1340612376924160  12   14
1628414210130481  7   18
1853020188884609  3   32
1853088908328577  9   16
2251799813687849  2   51
2251806789442689  8   17
2384185796169257  5   22
3656158504062976  6   20
4185897925275026  11   15
4503599627373200  2   52
4503599627827472  4   26
4731091158953433  13   14
5559060566591460  3   33
9007199254743801  2   53
10001099511627776  10   16
11398896079244882  7   19
11920928961514468  5   23
15536767912476993  12   15
16677181699705873  3   34
16677300287543066  9   17
18014398509484900  2   54
18014398510013425  4   27
18014409529442560  8   18
21936950726143977  6   21
22224013651116032  14   14
36028797018966993  2   55
45967322049616577  11   16
50031545099042582  3   35
53132088082450132  13   15
59604644783353249  5   24
72057594037931072  2   56
72057594038542592  4   28
79792267577612001  7   20
100002015993900449  10   17
131621703955647040  6   22
144115188075859121  2   57
144115205059418913  8   19
150094635297045777  3   36
150094833656289489  9   18
184761021583202849  14   15
185165733871747072  12   16
288230376151715108  2   58
288230376152419025  4   29
298023223886718750  5   25
450283905891048016  3   37
505481300395601404  11   17
558545865884372548  7   21
576460752303426969  2   59
669920208810550337  13   16
789730223201638705  6   23
875787780761718750  15   15
1000003570467226624  10   18
1152921504606850576  2   60
1152921504607656976  4   30
1152921530206846976  8   20
1350851717673046961  3   38
1350852040360689868  9   19
1490116119396647001  5   26
2219193728977666753  12   17
2250010931847299072  14   16
2305843009213697673  2   61
3909821051077345937  7   22
4052555153019035586  3   39
4611686018427391748  2   62
4611686018428311425  4   31
4738381338512719872  6   24
5559981581902310713  11   18
7450580596938177032  5   27
7721329860319737601  15   16
8660320497414243870  13   17
9223372036854779777  2   63
9223372074677635169  8   21
10000006131066257801  10   19
12157665459056992801  3   40
12157665971056928801  9   20
18446744073709555712  2   64
18446744073710600192  4   32
26624490112266670080  12   18
27368747343485741790  7   23
28430288030173842001  6   25
30659724555890596833  14   17
36472996377170855324  3   41
36893488147419103232  16   16
36893488147419107457  2   65
37252902984636350993  5   28
61159206938673444510  11   19
73786976294838210820  2   66
73786976294839392385  4   33
73786976349714080000  8   22
100000010240000000000  10   20
101388548387203175168  15   17
109418989131512433297  3   42
109418989925792405790  9   21
112476229916823064297  13   18
147573952589676417417  2   67
170581728179887124032  6   26
186264514923116214274  5   29
191581231385152885825  7   24
295147905179352830480  2   68
295147905179354162192  4   34
319482212685541993009  12   19
328256967394537157134  3   43
343809097055019694337  16   17
427253667578218823680  14   18
590295810358705656473  2   69
590295810437016636993  8   23
672750199732560009201  11   20
931322574615502815625  5   30
984770902183611318065  3   44
984770903390880450673  9   22
1000000016679880978201  10   21
1023490369077856670025  6   27
1180591620717411308324  2   70
1180591620717412804049  4   35
1341068619670068416432  7   25
1461962343358908367736  13   19
1484638520651877849057  15   18
1654480523772673528354  17   17
2361183241434822611889  2   71
2954312706550833789768  3   45
3833764088447475122176  12   20
4656612873077421207276  5   31
4722366482869645218880  2   72
4722366482869646893312  4   36
4722366482979720527872  8   24
4843806013966239465472  16   18
5977102965634697281305  14   19
6140942214465297387520  6   28
7400250294535660643432  11   21
8862938119652501193265  3   46
8862938121453653757392  9   23
9387480337655786115825  7   26
9444732965739290432721  2   73
10000000026559922791424  10   22
16248996011806421522977  17   18
18889465931478580860260  2   74
18889465931478582728945  4   37
19005045694880799438801  13   20
22183559327560880657674  15   19
23283064365386996445057  5   32
26588814358957503391610  3   47
36845653286789487806617  6   29
37778931862957161715193  2   75
37778931863109749600193  8   25
46005127265197212852753  12   21
65712362363544740492746  7   27
75557863725914323424912  2   76
75557863725914325504272  4   38
75846305139481944586817  16   19
78692816150593075150848  18   18
79766443076872509973953  3   48
79766443079514317403585  9   24
81402749971158062524649  11   22
83669893825284801560576  14   20
100000000041426511213649  10   23
116415321826934853588518  5   33
151115727451828646844201  2   77
221073919720734086899776  6   30
239299329230617529707732  3   49
244552822542936127033092  17   19
247064683545828131823874  13   21
302231454903657293682628  2   78
302231454903657295989985  4   39
302231454903866120741120  8   26
332558441007965087890625  15   20
459986536544753453905313  7   28
552061451767439048642560  12   22
582076609134674117701049  5   34
604462909807314587359329  2   79
717897987691852588895249  3   50
717897987695667286035874  9   25
812362695653248917890473  18   19
895430244208047130160458  11   23
1000000000063403380965376  10   24
1171358819873919743356745  14   21
1208925819614629174712576  2   80
1208925819614629177266176  4   40
1209581179614629174706176  16   20
1326443518324401034902337  6   31
2153693963075557766443398  3   51
2417851639229258349418913  2   81
2417851639229540778948833  8   27
2910383045673370413850000  5   35
3211839160764912988240121  13   22
3219905755813196976713916  7   29
3956839311320627178247958  19   19
4077338606647572522401601  17   20
4835703278458516698831428  2   82
4835703278458516701650465  4   41
4987953217438059270041676  15   21
6461081889226673299072849  3   52
6461081889232102802611217  9   26
6624737288863861443140449  12   23
7958661109946401958133760  6   32
9671406556917033397656297  2   83
9849732677329292237880865  11   24
10000000000095367431640625  10   25
13010380216396078174437376  18   20
14551915228366851867106801  5   36
16398984285177094533693440  14   22
19342813113834066795305872  2   84
19342813113834066798410512  4   42
19342813113834444597297152  8   28
19344243682524308780627137  16   21
19383245667680019896945600  3   53
22539340290692279957863249  7   30
38685626227668133590604857  2   85
41753905917449478303513180  13   23
42832853457545958193355601  19   20
47751966659678406597819585  6   33
58149737003040059690547633  3   54
58149737003047685287875156  9   27
69121975855503814572721958  17   21
72759576141834259102547082  5   37
74818413306860160187442593  15   22
77371252455336267181202660  2   86
77371252455336267184614065  4   43
79496847239911191569498112  12   24
100000000000141167095653376  10   26
108347059436267907832845876  11   25
154742504910672534362398097  2   87
154742504910673034608803489  8   29
157775382034845834127656854  7   31
174449211009120179071336882  3   55
209715200000000000000000000  20   20
229585704479817820020970353  14   23
230099132687526122669662329  18   21
286511799958070433382914112  6   34
309485009821345068724788800  2   88
309485009821345068728529152  4   44
309488021182841407789924352  16   22
363797880709171295245250793  5   38
523347633027360537213687137  3   56
523347633027371115669464929  9   28
542800771250858851236953185  13   24
618970019642690137449570033  2   89
727457992333704231799337200  19   21
953962166500294774376689057  12   25
1000000000000205891132094649  10   27
1104427674243920680665037569  7   32
1122274413037117636022104982  15   23
1174629126474067918407215201  17   22
1191817653776391286947120537  11   26
1237940039285380274899132324  2   90
1237940039285380274903224849  4   45
1237940039285380930999124224  8   30
1570042899082081611640719756  3   57
1719070799748422592866923801  6   35
1818989403545856475920302324  5   39
2375370429446951548637196401  20   21
2475880078570760549798256729  2   91
3214199721453461059919675392  14   24
4131886033076557436047065088  18   22
4710128697246244834921798801  3   58
4710128697246259342067579558  9   29
4951760157141521099596505360  2   92
4951760157141521099600974352  4   46
4951766289751936780595145857  16   23
7056410016356932785415505318  13   25
7730993719707444566755537384  7   33
9094947017729282379252790625  5   40
9903520314283042199193002441  2   93
9903520314283043052084031233  8   31
10000000000000296196766695424  10   28
10314424798490535548348731392  6   36
11447545997383710511877263360  12   26
11685174036771965042762248842  21   21
13109994191505489427628015894  11   27
13602045395387109273447187769  19   22
14130386091738734504765016446  3   59
16834112700885515530508997249  15   24
19807040628566084398385996420  2   94
19807040628566084398390867265  4   47
19967709950899084465527991816  17   23
39614081257132168796771984193  2   95
42391158275216203514294649201  3   60
42391158275216223197294433201  9   30
42648469498686404044207947776  20   22
44998795843101276099134367249  14   25
45474735088646411895867809326  5   41
54116956037952111721483010993  7   34
61886548790943213279597420745  6   37
74350957764931823161604077201  18   23
79228162514264337593543959552  2   96
79228162514264337593549258752  4   48
79228162514264338693055578112  8   32
79228174630839128538650509312  16   24
91733330195749769531603352585  13   26
100000000000000420707233300201  10   29
127173474825648610542883526584  3   61
137370551967609473297883973329  12   27
138213776357206521921578463913  21   22
144209936106507527547143535953  11   28
158456325028528675187087910081  2   97
227373675443232059478890456857  5   42
252511683871746063232421875000  15   25
257904243416235317958787975746  19   23
316912650057057350374175810948  2   98
316912650057057350374181566145  4   49
339448962112406887326061532545  17   24
371319292745659279665201102400  6   38
378818692265664781747056922818  7   35
381520424476945831628650137137  3   62
381520424476945858068272059480  9   31
629983141346387198306510323712  14   26
633825300114114700748351612489  2   99
633825300114114702154760220929  8   33
682855754728439114793293447168  22   22
840576955831334586342923895201  20   23
1000000000000000590490000000000  10   30
1136868377216160297393945836568  5   43
1144561273430837494885949946474  3   63
1192533292516544571712213984384  13   27
1267650600228229401496703215376  2   100
1267650600228229401496709455376  4   50
1267650623511293766883666096001  16   25
1338265824199474286821115953152  18   24
1586309297171503774924202410720  11   29
1648446623609744762216132902912  12   28
2227915756473955677976659739857  6   39
2535301200456458802993406420953  2   101
2616052459228913777816325459284  21   23
2651730845859653471857387545697  7   36
3433683820292512484657849351425  3   64
3433683820292512519842221178113  9   32
3787675245783611671539876316001  15   26
4898930430490756842869366562145  19   24
5070602400912917605986812831908  2   102
5070602400912917605986819586705  4   51
5070602400912917607772606726400  8   34
5684341886080801486969159056849  5   44
5770627994425011513613642256682  17   25
8419259736788826438132968480177  22   23
8819763978055700119576496777513  14   27
10000000000000000819628286980801  10   31
10141204801825835211973625653617  2   103
10301051460877537453973547542468  3   65
13367494538843734067842941976576  6   40
15502932802668898326692033053169  13   28
16781235988717840603673710821376  20   24
17449402268886425033258803753801  11   30
18562115921017574302548095548340  7   37
19781359483314504342195729754993  12   29
20282409603651670423947251296832  2   104
20282409603651670423947258597632  4   52
20282409647260413323376125345792  16   26
24088673762858333010767090334193  18   25
28421709430404007434845155231250  5   45
30903154382632612361920642091025  3   66
30903154382632612408332126205482  9   33
40564819207303340847894502583057  2   105
40564819207303340850146377962657  8   35
41760935999695824068710065821134  23   23
54204678106500758618679652975905  21   24
56815128664549597645363089558018  15   27
80204967233062404407037825963697  6   41
81129638414606681695789005155300  2   106
81129638414606681695789013034545  4   53
92709463147897837085761925711350  3   67
93076859486136798707904776296124  19   25
98100667143750155827123415402145  17   26
100000000000000001125899906842624  10   32
123476695691429994946059724390400  14   28
129934811447123020117286561281041  7   38
142108547152020037174225059478601  5   46
162259276829213363391578010299577  2   107
167566606145758453496034447327232  22   24
191943424957750505912623737696642  11   31
201538126434621411427216914973962  13   29
237376313799770337769950291431424  12   30
278128389443693511257285776546193  3   68
278128389443693511318002768998225  9   34
324518553658426726783156020587920  2   108
324518553658426726783156029079312  4   54
324518553658426726785977130483712  8   36
324518553738193169860028530439617  16   27
335553414947017729282379150390625  20   25
433595895276486083604393970892800  18   26
481229803398374426442203944188480  6   42
535823088031930481975544151644865  23   24
649037107316853453566312041164393  2   109
710542735760100185871124496923132  5   47
834385168331080533771857329023792  3   69
852226929929026929437422228846657  15   28
909543680129861140820342250895822  7   39
1000000000000000001531578985264449  10   33
1136499539598167498800201218286126  21   25
1298074214633706907132624082317124  2   110
1298074214633706907132624091455649  4   55
1667711324322382250589093493726220  17   27
1728673739677768659799892745451065  14   29
1768454184544130901557473069952457  19   26
2111377674535255321574412273173889  11   32
2503155504993241601315571986428849  3   70
2503155504993241601394387624757724  9   35
2596148429267413814265248164622369  2   111
2596148429267413814268760644063969  8   37
2619995643649960903610551432833049  13   30
2667471553700568248898162945687552  24   24
2848515765597238463610187285726849  12   31
2887378820390246558653197052303465  6   43
3552713678800500929355621592694593  5   48
3641208380060290648646463306863057  22   25
5192296858534827628530496329232640  2   112
5192296858534827628530496339054592  4   56
5192296858677561978477171275988992  16   28
6366805760909027985741598979224001  7   40
6710906328148895209409152340197376  20   26
7509466514979724803946715958615458  3   71
7804725642495302907668611607106201  18   27
10000000000000000002064377754059776  10   34
10384593717069655257060992658452961  2   113
11187876119071565503348037263205568  23   25
12783403948867568299980355752800324  15   29
17324272922341479351919151641956352  6   44
17763568394002504646778106971928374  5   49
20769187434139310514121985316893380  2   114
20769187434139310514121985327436385  4   57
20769187434139310514126333109018880  8   38
22528399544939174411840147875145889  3   72
22528399544939174411941707831441057  9   36
23225154419887808191543874310035948  11   33
23862233616248485046193132474062297  21   26
24201432355485073718841037243826176  14   30
28351092480864262686237005875592129  17   28
33600616513503347404797680951794702  19   27
34059943367449308902493466071872228  13   31
34182189187166853264290346572972032  12   32
35562372323207319916133576686141249  24   25
41538374868278621028243970633773993  2   115
44567640326363195900190240728841888  7   41
67585198634817523235520443624706940  3   73
79995000268485778198095856853319680  22   26
83076749736557242056487941267534992  2   116
83076749736557242056487941278838032  4   58
83076749736807488530168288616309057  16   29
88817841970012523233890533759765625  5   50
100000000000000000002758547353515625  10   35
103945637534048876111514874617620601  6   45
134217770391158275216203514294433201  20   27
140485060630123916641507092767703040  18   28
166153499473114484112975882535056761  2   117
166153499473114484112981234544303553  8   39
177635683940025046467781066894531250  25   25
191751059232898435575491363525390625  15   30
202755595904452569706561330873358993  3   74
202755595904452569706691292612748846  9   37
254402911299131746297259216731949265  23   26
255476698618765889621208289397432825  11   34
311973482284542371301330552361309297  7   42
332306998946228968225951765070100068  2   118
332306998946228968225951765082203505  4   59
338820052976785092851109742209886785  14   31
410186270246002227004315618546485633  12   33
442779263776840735197801339567888513  13   32
444089209850062616169452667581353376  5   51
481968572114008062828141898337909806  17   29
501097169733194832470153490157237368  21   27
608266787713357709119683992619283182  3   75
623673825204293256669089207357426752  6   46
638411687059052968161013748384747633  19   28
664613997892457936451903530140186449  2   119
777338493235300870639470742394109952  24   26
1000000000000000000003656158440062976  10   36
1329227995784915872903807060280358976  2   120
1329227995784915872903807060293304576  4   60
1329227995784915872903813613880344576  8   40
1329227995785346340113807060280344576  16   30
1759624537630700198637557167999460617  22   27
1824800363140073127359051977857022897  3   76
1824800363140073127359217193957846769  9   38
2183814375991796599109312524572443450  7   43
2220446049250313080847263336561844657  5   52
2457219879258280669724058501120110001  25   26
2528731089538420637464822941346299529  18   29
2658455991569831745807614120560703793  2   121
2684354647732524600823436081182539776  20   28
2810243684806424785157763060726451726  11   35
2876265888493284765289362297566789326  15   31
3742042951225759540014535198077994465  6   47
4743480741674981883292064017201233920  14   32
4922235242952026706423533926815109120  12   34
5316911983139663491615228241121393188  2   122
5316911983139663491615228241135224145  4   61
5474401089420219382077155933570208296  3   77
5756130429098929132996425491382712366  13   33
5844045430713770632139718622054675130  23   27
8193465725827679572854001028792218849  17   30
10000000000000000000004808584372417849  10   37
10523018985121038257342040961469473489  21   28
10633823966279326983230456482242771737  2   123
10633823966279326983230464467167985729  8   41
11102230246251565404236316681326398618  5   53
12129822000692483091090492510943759848  19   29
12312239160414314621593348576800407552  26   26
15286700631942576193765186088554636065  7   44
16423203268260658146231467800709729841  3   78
16423203268260658146231676529070414048  9   39
18460091778723266910795942428467132065  24   27
21267647932558653966460912964485528592  2   124
21267647932558653966460912964500289552  4   62
21267647932559381389582660149749341697  16   31
22452257707354557240087211136023265280  6   48
30912680532870672635804974640729720497  11   36
38711128740778273498128183088979640320  22   28
42535295865117307932921825928971042057  2   125
43143988327398957279342419750374600193  15   32
45517159608290760844793714778287898624  18   30
49269609804781974438694403402128258906  3   79
53687091376994576151109753197786640401  20   29
55511151231257827021181583405000180649  5   54
56119418018971184730301267397159876932  25   27
59066822915424320451824579425520737393  12   35
66408730383449731654137887980859649473  14   33
74829695578286078094567232718710148393  13   34
85070591730234615865843651857942068740  2   126
85070591730234615865843651857957805825  4   63
85070591730234615865843661540594049280  8   42
100000000000000000000006278211847988224  10   38
107006904423598033356356300758607237932  7   45
134395779951925146963005629707810699233  23   28
134713546244127343440523266756597336097  6   49
139288917338873564578192180232646403344  17   31
147808829414345923316083210206383809601  3   80
147808829414345923316083472350383297601  9   40
170141183460469231731687303715884121857  2   127
176482312353646748226944999299114553465  26   27
220983352233660046502185287191338126610  21   29
230466617908817829715509519405933293401  19   30
277555756156289135105907917023208362500  5   55
340039485861577398992584799927541447384  11   37
340282366920938463463374607431768227840  2   128
340282366920938463463374607431784988672  4   64
340282366920939672389194222060942917632  16   32
442555446422920909403146370069385183232  24   28
443426488243037769948249630619150424244  3   81
647159824910983852445103850763613902832  15   33
680564733841876926926749214863536439553  2   129
680564733841876926926749226551736700513  8   43
708801874985091845386082688347890778112  12   36
749048330965186233494494103130382150865  7   46
808281277464764060643139600472161293376  6   50
819308872942959180024285911047721345473  18   31
851643467938976245039496939059670607833  22   29
886852976486075539896499261238299785606  27   27
929722225368296220487989197108051197952  14   34
972786042517719014292848800932863684232  13   35
1000000000000000000000008140406085191601  10   39
1073741824348678440100000000000000000000  20   30
1330279464729113309844748891857450229777  3   82
1330279464729113309844749219239384072370  9   41
1361129467683753853853498429727072862724  2   130
1361129467683753853853498429727090696449  4   65
1387778780781445675529539585114076122401  5   56
1389288689815394899967521214498244988193  25   28
2367911594760505931470333965454541844993  17   32
2722258935367507707706996859454145708809  2   131
3091062959814255272215316579358416079052  23   29
3740434344477351388916714277413605409193  11   38
3990838394187339929534246675572349607014  3   83
4203814289170616626362037441730686484480  26   28
4378865740068379748084651264907446852090  19   31
4640650299577517303520051333566036654601  21   30
4849687664788584363858837602756814048057  6   51
5243338316756303634461458719368574576006  7   47
5444517870735015415413993718908291400720  2   132
5444517870735015415413993718908310358032  4   66
5444517870735015415413993732956515008512  8   44
5444517870735017393399195181467169317377  16   33
6938893903907228377647697925568228645182  5   57
8505622499821102144582714636120669969873  12   37
9707397373664756981388253830346544295649  15   34
10000000000000000000000010485760000000000  10   40
```

Comment: I think this answer could be greatly improved by providing both of the representations of the numbers in the left column.

Comment: @Ryan, I found no duplicates. I put as many lines as I could given the bound of 30,000 characters. There are some with many identical digits, in the last ten lines, four in a row, $(2,132); (4,66); (8,44); (16,33).$ The values agree for many digits but are not equal.

Comment: Oh, I get it now.  You are showing every combination made without $0$ or $1$.  That clarification might be nice, because I read your answer right after reading Omnomnomnom's, thinking that you were listing counterexamples.

Comment: @Ryan, it accepted the edit, one line at the beginning.